# Setting and querying data inside sub-collections?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on the createGroup() functionality for my application.

And this is the data structure I have planned:

```
Groups(collection)

    GroupID(document)

        name: value,
        description: value,
        createdOn: value,

        Members(subcollection)
            userId1(document)
                role: value,
                joinedOn: value,
            userId2(document)
                role: value,
                joinedOn: value,

    GroupId(document)
         ...and so on...
```

I am trying to achieve this :
[image]
[image]
I was made the above structure manually in the console, but I don't know how to make it programmatically??

From what I have understood after reading through the docs, I can use transactions like this:

```
createGroup() {
    var docRef = firestore()
      .collection('Groups')
      .doc();
    firestore().runTransaction(transaction => {
      return transaction.get(docRef).then(doc => {
        transaction.set(docRef, {
          name: this.name,
          desc: this.desc,
          createdOn: new Date(),
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

But I still can't figure out how to create a members sub-collection and add users to it, since we have only four methods to work with in transactions: `set(), get(), delete() and update()`
Please tell me how should I progress further??

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what the trouble is here.  It's possible create documents in any collection or subcollection at any time, even if a parent document doesn't exist yet.

Comment: The problem is that I want some field values to be set in the parent document and also a Members sub-collection together

Comment: Then use a batch write or transaction.

Comment: Okay, @DougStevenson I'll try that

Comment: @DougStevenson I read the docs about transactions, was able to set the field values in the groupId(document). But I still can't figure out how to create a members sub-collection and add users to it, since we have only four methods to work with in transactions: ```set(), get(), delete() and update()```.
I have edited the question with new createGroup() method using transactions
I'm new at this, please help me out.

Comment: You don't have to do anything to create a subcollection.  Just start writing documents to it as if it already exists, and it will appear in the console.